# Циклические включения

Tags: c++, include

Не могу разобраться с циклическими инклюдами.
Есть файл `a.h`, в нем находится определение класса `A`:

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H    

#include <c.h>

enum class Props {*};

class A
{
***
private:  
    C var;    
}

#endif // A_H
```

А также файлы `b.h` и `c.h` с определениями соответствующих классов:

```
// b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H 

#include "a.h"

class B
{
prublic:
    void foo(Props p); // 'Props' has not been declared
}

#endif // B_H

// c.h
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H 

#include "b.h"

class C : public B 
{
***
}

#endif // C_H
```

Объясните пожалуйста как это работает и как этого избегать. Раньше сталкивался с этим. Решалось предварительным объявлением (forward declaration) классов. Но в этом случае не очень понимаю что делать, да и хотелось бы наконец разобраться.

Comment: циклические инклуды невозможны и в данном случае forward declaration невозможно. Необходимо менять архитектуру

Comment: Поскольку класс А зависит от С, С зависит от В, а В зависит от Props, логичнее всего переместить `enum class Props` из a.h в b.h и убрать `#include "a.h"` из b.h

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы минимизировать зависимости в заголовках можно отделить интерфейс от реализации, внутренней структуры.

Т.е. в заголовках только интерфейс (функции). Все закрытые члены либо в классе-наследнике интерфейса, либо в структуре, которая является собственно реализацией, а в интерфейсе только объявлена в приватной части.